# Error in creating a conda environment using 'python setup.py develop'

Tags: conda, flow-project

At first, after I run the command `conda env create -f environment.yml`. I recieve the following warning:

```
Warning : you have pip-isntalled dependencies in your environment file, but you do not list pip itself as one of your conda dependencies...`
```

Then I add `pip==19.3.1` in the `environment.yml`. This is my `environment.yml`:

```
   name: flow

dependencies:
    - python==3.6.8
    - scipy==1.1.0
    - lxml==4.2.4
    - six==1.11.0
    - path.py
    - python-dateutil==2.7.3
    - tensorflow==1.9.0
    - cloudpickle==1.2.1
    - setuptools==41.0.0
    - pip==19.3.1
    - pip:
        - gym==0.14.0
        - pyprind==2.11.2
        - nose2==0.8.0
        - cached_property
        - joblib==0.10.3
        - matplotlib==3.0.0
        - dill
        - lz4
        - ray==0.7.3
        - setproctitle
        - psutil
        - opencv-python
        - boto3==1.4.8
        - redis~=2.10.6
```

When I run `python setup.py develop`, I recieve the following error:

```
error: cloudpickle 0.5.3 is installed but cloudpickle~=1.2.0 is required by {'gym'}
```

Should I reinstall `cloudpickle~=1.2.0`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing this out! If you post an issue on Github, we will add that upgrade to our environment file. However, this error is almost certainly not a breaking error as we don't do any cloudpickle calls in gym.

Comment: When I try to reinstall the package"cloudpickle", it told me that the package "cloudpickle==1.2.1“ has already exist. Then I run the rest command in the Installation tutorial, all is well. I don't konw why  there is  such error.